Using Schwarz Pick to find best estimate
Let $F$ be the family of all holomorphic functions
$$f: \mathbb H \to \Omega = \{z\in \mathbb C : |z|>1\} \text{ such that } f(i)=2$$
Give the best estimate for $|f(3i)|$ for $f\in F$.
I tried applying Schwarz Pick, with the composition:
$$g(z):=\frac{1}{z} \circ f \circ K(z) : \mathbb D \to \mathbb D$$
where $K(z) = i \frac{(1+z)}{1-z}$ then according to Schwarz-Pick,
$$\left|\frac{g(1/2) - g(0) }{1-\bar{g(0)} g(1/2)} \right| \leq 
 \frac{1}{2} \implies \left| \frac{\frac{1}{f(3i)} - 1/2}{1- \frac{1}{2f(3i)}} \right| \leq 1/2$$
which only gets me the bound:
$$\frac{3}{4} \leq |f(3i)|$$
This could be due to a simple mistake or maybe just need to use a different approach. I appreciate any suggestions!

That’s a mistake. The last inequality is equivalent to $\lvert f(3\mathrm i)^{-1}-\tfrac 25 \rvert \leq \tfrac 25$.

It seems that we would still get a lower bound right?

It is correct that $g(z):=\frac{1}{z} \circ f \circ K(z)$ maps $ \mathbb D \to \mathbb D$ so that the Schwarz-Pick theorem can be applied. But this approach does not use the fact that $g(z) \ne 0$ in $\Bbb D$, and therefore the obtained bound is not optimal.
We can proceed as follows: $f \circ K$ maps the unit disk to $\{ w : |w| > 1\}$. In particular it is a holomorphic nonzero function in a simply connected domain. It follows that $f \circ K = \exp \circ h$ With some holomorphic function $h$ in $\Bbb C$.
$f(K(0)) = f(i) = 2$ and $h$ can be chosen such that $h(0) = \ln 2$. Also
$$
 |f(K(z))| = e^{\operatorname{Re}h(z)} > 1 \implies \operatorname{Re}h(z) > 0
$$
for all $z \in \Bbb D$, i.e. $h$ maps the unit disk into the right halfplane. Then
$$
 g(z) = \frac{h(z)-\ln 2}{h(z)+\ln 2}
$$
maps $ \mathbb D \to \mathbb D$  with $g(0) = 0$.
It follows that $|g(z)| \le |z|$ by the Schwarz Lemma, and in particular $|g(1/2)| \le 1/2$.
Now we can give upper and lower bounds for $|f(3i)|$:
$$
 |f(3i)| =  |f(K(\frac 12))| = e^{\operatorname{Re} h(1/2)}
$$
with
$$
 h(\frac 12) = \ln 2 \cdot \frac{1+g(1/2)}{1-g(1/2)} \, .
$$
$\zeta \mapsto (1+\zeta)/(1-\zeta)$ maps the disk $|z| \le 1/2$ to a disk lying inside the strip $\{ z : 1/3 \le \operatorname{Re} z \le 3\}$. It follows that
$$
 -\frac 13 \le \operatorname{Re} \left( \frac{1+g(1/2)}{1-g(1/2)}\right) \le 3
$$
so that
$$
 \frac 13 \ln 2 \le \operatorname{Re} h(1/2) \le 3 \ln 2
$$
and finally
$$
1.2599 \approx 2^{1/3} \le |f(3i)| \le 2^3  = 8\, .
$$
These bounds are sharp. The extremal functions can be found by choosing $f$ such that $g(z) = z$ and $g(z) = -z$, respectively.
Spoiler: The upper bound $|f(3i)|=8$ is attained for

$f(z) = \exp(-i z \ln 2)$

and the lower bound $|f(3i)|=2^{1/3}$ is attained for

$f(z) = \exp(\frac iz \ln 2)$

